# table columns hide when button is clicked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this function which is responsible of making the table `tr` and `th` collapse. But in fact I don't want to collapse .

i  want to hide the `th` but now i am collapsing the table column now while collapsing i am showing heading with "-" symbol also for expanding i am showing heading with "+" symbol.

i want to show when click "-" i want to hide the column and in header i want to show only"+" when i press + i want to show the column and heading with "-".

any one hide me how to do that .thanks

Here is my code

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/22/

```
$(function() {
    $('table tbody tr:odd').addClass('alt');

    $('table tbody tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
     });

       $('tr th:gt(0)').click(function() {

    var index = (this.cellIndex + 1);
    var cells = $('table tr > :nth-child(' + index + ')');
    cells.toggleClass('collapsed');

    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).find('span').html('<b>+</b>');
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('span').html('<b>-</b>');
    }

    if ($('table tr > th:not(.collapsed)').length)
        $('table').removeClass('collapsed');
    else
        $('table').addClass('collapsed');
});
```

First show the data in table

[image]

when i click the red button i want

[image]

Comment: your paragraph is too confusing to read....please rephrase!!!!

Comment: And why do you not just use `:hover` in your CSS? No JavaScript needed unless you are supporting ancient browsers.

Comment: i m not sure what you want. but as i understand that you want something like [http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/hidetablecols.html](http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/hidetablecols.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want either. "collapse" is not even the right word for what the function does. Maybe show some mockup screenshots of what you want to happen?

Comment: @MrLister see the screen shot please